# Comparison operator `<=>` and booleans

Tags: ruby

The `<=>` operator does not handle booleans well.

```
true <=> true # => 0
true <=> false # => nil
```

Is this behavior intended by design or am I missing something? I expect:

```
true <=> false # => 1
false <=> true # => -1
```

---

**Edit**
This is what I was looking for:

```
false.to_i <=> true.to_i # => -1
```

Comment: Why do you think `true <=> false` should be `1`, etc.? It does not seem to make sense to compare the size or order between boolean values.

Comment: I was assuming that true would be evaluated as 1 and false as 0

Comment: Why do you assume so? `true` is `true`, `1` is `1`. They are different.

Comment: Was thinking it was a value comparison and not object comparison.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "value comparison" or "object comparison".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<=>` operator isn't really a "combined boolean"; it is for *ordering* items of the same class, *if* they have an order defined. Numbers are ordered; `1` is greater than `0` and `0` is less than `8675309`. Boolean values don't have an inherent order; `true` isn't greater than `false` or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same class. `true` is a singleton of `TrueClass`, while `false` is a singleton of `FalseClass`. You're comparing apples and oranges (or, in `true <=> true` case, an apple with the same apple).

For curiosity's sake, why do you think `true <=> false` should equal `1`? EDIT: beaten to it by sawa

Comment: Ahh I was assuming that true would be evaluated as 1 and false as 0.

Comment: It is the internal implementation of C, and many other languages. But it doesn't really make any kind of semantic sense.